# (Simple code) SwingWorker deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, deadlock, swingworker

I am creating a java program that will open up a splash image, then every 15 minutes, display an (new or old) image loaded from the function CallMinutesInternational... (in the doInBackground)

This image, for the sake of simplicity, changes every few intervals.

Now I have a very **strange** bug.... The code below will only deadlock on a VISTA machine, but will not deadlock on my machine, nor on Microsoft Server 2008 SP1 machine.

This leads me to believe that there is something that I am not getting.

I have excluded all swing calls and creation in the process(). However, after 20-50 intervals, my computer at work will deadlock (Vista)

I would be grateful if anyone can explain why this would occur. I have spent many days trying to fix this simple... nuisance of an error, but cannot get my head around it.

Any suggestions?

```
public class GUIThreadremaster extends JComponent {



static JFrame f = new JFrame();
static JLabel label = new JLabel();
static final String version = "v.72";
static final String splashUrl = "http://s3.postimg.org/48nx9vkur/image.jpg";




public static void main(String[] args) {



            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new GUIThreadremaster();
                n.execute();


            }});

   // A.GUIThread();

}



public static SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage> n = new SwingWorker<Void,BufferedImage>()
        {
        //Semaphore block = new Semaphore(0);
        boolean b = false;


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground()
                    throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 URL url = null;
                 BufferedImage image = null;
                 String s;
                 int i = 1;

                 Thread.sleep(15000);
                while(!b)
                {


                     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + i);
                     i++;


               s =  CallMinInternational.updateGraph(CallMinInternational.queryResultsLive(false));
                    //System.out.println("test");
                //  s = splashUrl;
                url = new URL(s);
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(url);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                //System.out.println("UPDATED : " );

                publish(image);
                 Thread.sleep(15000);
                }


                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<BufferedImage> chunks) 
            {
                ImageIcon tmp = new ImageIcon();
                tmp.setImage(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));

                JLabel labelnew = new JLabel();
                labelnew.setIcon(tmp);
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
                //System.out.println("test");
                f.getContentPane().removeAll();
                f.getContentPane().add(labelnew);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();

                f.setLocation(f.getX(), f.getY());



            }

        };

public GUIThreadremaster() {


                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                           try {
                                f.getContentPane().removeAll();


                               //String path = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l";
                               // System.out.println("Get Image from " + path);
                               // URL url = new URL(path);
                                //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
                                URL url = new URL(splashUrl);
                                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);

                                label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                                //JFrame f = new JFrame();
                                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                f.getContentPane().add(label);
                                f.pack();
                                f.setLocation(f.getX(), f.getY());
                                f.setVisible(true);
                                f.setResizable(false);
                                f.getContentPane().repaint();
                                f.setTitle("I.O.M.S - 360 Communications " + version);

                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                                exp.printStackTrace();
                            } 




        //   n.execute();



 }
}
```

NEW CODE : (TrashGod)

```
public class GUIThreadremaster extends JComponent {



static JFrame f = new JFrame();
static JLabel label = new JLabel();
static final String version = "v.75";
static final String splashUrl = "http://s3.postimg.org/48nx9vkur/image.jpg";




public static void main(String[] args) {



            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new GUIThreadremaster();
                n.execute();


            }});

   // A.GUIThread();

}



public static SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage> n = new SwingWorker<Void,BufferedImage>()
        {
        //Semaphore block = new Semaphore(0);
        boolean b = false;


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground()
                    throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 URL url = null;
                 BufferedImage image = null;
                 String s;
                 int i = 1;

                 Thread.sleep(15000);
                while(!b)
                {


                     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + i);
                     i++;


                 s =  CallMinInternational.updateGraph(CallMinInternational.queryResultsLive(false));
                    //System.out.println("test");
                //  s = splashUrl;
                url = new URL(s);
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(url);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                //System.out.println("UPDATED : " );

                publish(image);
                 Thread.sleep(15000);
                }


                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<BufferedImage> chunks) 
            {
                ImageIcon tmp = new ImageIcon();
                tmp.setImage(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));


                label.setIcon(tmp);
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
                //System.out.println("test");
                f.pack();




            }

        };

public GUIThreadremaster() {


                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                           try {
                                f.getContentPane().removeAll();


                               //String path = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l";
                               // System.out.println("Get Image from " + path);
                               // URL url = new URL(path);
                                //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
                                URL url = new URL(splashUrl);
                                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);

                                label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                                //JFrame f = new JFrame();
                                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                f.getContentPane().add(label);
                                f.pack();
                                f.setLocation(f.getX(), f.getY());
                                f.setVisible(true);
                                f.setResizable(false);
                                f.getContentPane().repaint();
                                f.setTitle("I.O.M.S - 360 Communications " + version);

                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                                exp.printStackTrace();
                            } 




        //   n.execute();



}
}
```

Comment: Does `updateGraph()` update the GUI from `doInBackground()`?

Comment: hello trashgod. It does not... :( The two functions together, just produce a new image link.

Comment: If it is of any help, the inner function, is a UDP request for a timestamp and database selects (24), and the outer function , produces a link to that graph, which works on a 2008 server and on my mac, but not on VISTA. The program will deadlock on vista after a few requests. TrashGod, I don't see anything wrong with the logic of this program. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do the machines have different numbers of CPU cores? If so, that might (partly) explain why the behaviour is different - may not be an OS issue. When you say `deadlock`, what do you see - how have you confirmed that it is a deadlock?

Comment: I have command line statements being printed every 15 seconds. Then... they just stop abruptly at around 20-60 updates.
The Vista machines have 8 cores, my mac has 2. This problem only occurs on the Vista machine. The server machine has 1 core.
Is there anything wrong with my code? I mean... it is rather simple, and trivial.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, all machines are running the same java JRE

Comment: You might also look at updating the label's icon, rather than replacing the label each time.

Comment: Technically speaking trashgod, could this cause problems?

Comment: DNA, can i change the core affinity of the program to just 1 core and would that affect how the program will behave? Or even two?
#DNA #trashgod 
#respect

Comment: I never got back to you guys but this code is correct and works. The reason my "UI DEADLOCKED" had nothing to due with the UI. It was actually a networking livelock.